# Should I build my ios apps for arm64?

Tags: xcode, armv7, arm64

Right now I'm only building for `armv7` and `armv7s`, should I be building for `arm64` as well? What's the benefit?

Even still, shouldn't `arm64` devices be backwards compatible with `armv7`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an email chain with a colleague I coincidentally found out that [`arm64` is going to be **required** along with `iOS8 SDK` in order to submit an app to the Apple store as of February 2015 according to this article](http://9to5mac.com/2014/10/20/apple-to-require-ios-apps-and-updates-to-use-ios-8-sdk-and-include-64-bit-support-from-february-2015/?pushup=1)